# error C2664: 'imgGrab' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'Int8 **' to 'void **'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing an x64 DLL using Visual Studio 2008.

The compiler error

```
error C2664: 'imgGrab' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'Int8 **' to 'void **'
```

occurs at this line;

```
Int8* ImaqBuffer;
Int32 err = imgGrab (Sid, &ImaqBuffer, TRUE);
```

I've managed to get it to compile by doing;

```
Int32 err = imgGrab (Sid, (void **)&ImaqBuffer, TRUE);
```

but I think this is wrong. Am I right in thinking this is wrong? If so how do I fix it. I suspect its a compiler setting in Visual Studio because the code compiles ok in the sample project from the manufacturer.

Comment: why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: It just looks wrong. But I could be wrong!

Comment: Okay in C, not in C++.  So the sample project was probably written in C.

Comment: Yes i guess its really c/c++ code. So you think me casting to (void **) is ok?

Comment: @Doug if you're in C yes, in C++ you should use `reinterpret_cast<void**>` instead

Comment: OK great thanks. Its an *.c file so Im happy now.

Comment: Hum... Do you mean that the sample project doesn't need the cast?